# How to get a full name function

Tags: broken-code

I have some function in string format,and I can get it short name without context

```
First[Defer /@ ToExpression[#, InputForm, 
  HoldComplete]] & /@ {"GeneralUtilities`AllSameBy","GeneralUtilities`Buzz"}
```

> `{AllSameBy,Buzz}`

But actually `` {GeneralUtilities`AllSameBy,GeneralUtilities`Buzz} ``(it is not a string form but a symbol form) is expected.How to implement this?

Comment: ``GeneralUtilities`QualifiedSymbolName`` is HoldAllComplete, and only works with Symbol arguments. Use ``ToExpression[#, InputForm, GeneralUtilities`QualifiedSymbolName]& /@ {"GeneralUtilities`AllSameBy", 
  "GeneralUtilities`Buzz"}`` instead.

Comment: It gives you the same thing that ``{GeneralUtilities`QualifiedSymbolName[AllSameBy], 
 GeneralUtilities`QualifiedSymbolName[Buzz]}`` does, which you said is what you want.

Comment: @CarlWoll I'm sorry,I have not noted that before.I have updated that

Comment: If ``"GeneralUtilities`"`` is on the context path, then the context will not be displayed. If it is not on the context path, then the context will be displayed. What is the reason that you want to see the context?

Comment: @CarlWoll I have known what you have said,you mean If we ``$ContextPath=DeleteCases[$ContextPath,"GeneralUtilities`"]``.Then the context will show.Well,I have to say I really don't know this knowledge.And do you mind I compose that as an answer?